# In Rails folder structure, where should I store a text file to call it as a string inside a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to parse a haml template to a variable using HAML::Engine inside a model.

Where in the rails app folder structure should I store my files (one for each template) and how can I call them as a string in the model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using what Sameera stated, by configuring your app to load directories, I would probably put it in a new folder in the 'lib' directory.

You can then have your rails app to load everything in 'lib' by putting this in your application.rb file.

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure that this is the answer to your question, But with rails you can always create extra folders (other than default folder structure given by rails),

But remember to load them when your app starts, in rails3 its in

'application.rb'

following line

config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

And IMO its not a bad thing to create an extra folder to make your code more organize.

HTH

cheers

sameera